# how to automatically remove/hide the data on the gridview after 24 hours

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a work that i display all of the bounced back email from EWS and i want to automatically remove or hide the data after 24 hours and display the new data. and here's my code to display the data

```
public void LoadResult()
    {

        EmailMethods email = new EmailMethods();

        email.EmailServer = "https://SampleEWS.asmx";
        email.AccountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Account"];
        email.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Secret"];
        email.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
        email.GetEmails();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Sender", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("DateCreated", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("EmailHeader", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ErrorTwo", typeof(string));



        foreach (Item item in email.EmailList)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item.Subject, item.DisplayTo, item.DateTimeCreated, item.Body, matchingMessage);

        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

the EmailMethods is my class that gets all of the undelivered/bounced back emails and here's my gidview code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" Height="423px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="Date and Time" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ErrorTwo" HeaderText="Error" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Receiver">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Sender") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Sender") %>'></asp:LinkButton> <%--OnClientClick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'; return false"--%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Email Error" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email Body">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Button ID="txtItemBody"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailHeader") %>' Width="100px" Enabled="false"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Email ">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Button runat="server"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" Text="View Email" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="whitesmoke" ForeColor="#0a0014" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#0a0014" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

and also i set this to refresh the page every 1 min

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60" />
```

can anyone help me or give some hints to fix my work thanks

Comment: Is the `DateTimeCreated` the time you're measuring the age from? Perhaps you can make a timer to iterate through the `dt` every minute or so and see if `DateTimeCreated` was more than 24 hours ago and then just delete the row?

Comment: As above, but instead of "delete", just filter the result set by calculating the difference from "current date or datetime"

Comment: thank you for those information i'll try to research now about the time and date and also the creation date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your `dt.Rows.Add(...)` method with the if condition to check if it's older than one day:

```
if (item.DateTimeCreated > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1.0))
{
    dt.Rows.Add(item.Subject, item.DisplayTo, item.DateTimeCreated, item.Body, matchingMessage);
}
```

Comment: i tried to wrap the dt.Rows.Add(...) with the if condition and after that it did not display the gridview. Thanks

Comment: @RobertJohnSustraido Maybe there is a time zone difference between your time stamps and the computer that is calculating. The best practice is to keep data in UTC, and then using `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now` when comparing time. You can transform the data to desired time zone after filtering is done.

Comment: thanks for the information. i tried to debug and the  dt.Rows.Add(...)inside the if condition it just like skipping and the gridview did not display on the webpage. but when i tried to place the  dt.Rows.Add(...) outside the if condition it display the gridview. can you help me with that please.

Comment: @RobertJohnSustraido Is the `item.DateTimeCreated` string of date? Please provide few time values that are not displayed, but should be. What is the local time of your computer at that time of execution?

Comment: i just added a convert.ToString because i got an error cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'string' the whole gridview did not display the local time of my computer is 4:00 am and the time of execution is 3:59 am i'd change the addDays to addMinutes to check if it will disappear the data after 1 min but the gridview did not display. Thank you so much for the reply

Comment: @RobertJohnSustraido If the value is already of type DateTime, then just remove `DateTime.Parse` part, and it will work. There is no need to convert it twice. I updated my answer.

Comment: i think it cant see the dt.Rows.Add(...) inside the if condition. because still it did not display the whole gridview. i tried to debug again sir and it just skip the dt.Rows.Add(...) inside the if condition. Thank you so much for the reply

Comment: @RobertJohnSustraido You might be missing the `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"` attribute in your GridView next to `ID="GridView1"`. Is that the issue?

Comment: my comment wasnt send. thank you so much that solution works in my program.